# How to add classpath in gradle compileJava task?

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

How to add classpath in gradle compileJava task?

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.compileJava {
      //add classpath
    }
}
```

It not add:

```
dependencies {
 compileOnly ''
}
```

Comment: I assume you wish to add to the classpath so that Java will use that classpath during compilation. Also, generally speaking, you shouldn't need to do this. I suggest looking to use dependencies or other Gradle mechanisms that automatically manipulate the classpath. However, I have encountered situations where a Gradle plugin was broken and I needed to manipulate the classpath directly myself. So... it is valid in some cases to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
compileJava {
    classpath += files(['src/main/coolbeans'])
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html

And https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html